# How we can add unicode Text in MySQL using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

How we can add unicode Text in MySQL using JAVA and reading it using JAVA

Comment: I had the same problem and i solved it and posted it in my blog see the links
[Unicode tutorial](http://uwudamith.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/how-to-insert-unicode-values-to-mysql-using-java/) I think this will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the character set of your MySQL `VARCHAR` column [should be UTF-8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Then, you should just be able to use [`Statement.setString()` without worry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE COFFEES SET SALES = ? WHERE COF_NAME LIKE ? ");
updateSales.setInt(1, 75); 
updateSales.setString(2, "Colombian"); 
updateSales.executeUpdate():
```

Things to be careful of:

- If you are reading text from a file, make sure you are reading the file in the right character set. See the constructor of [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).
- Be careful if you have columns in the database that are not in UTF-8 format!

That's all I can think of at the moment.